# Screensaver run only short - JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, screensaver

I have a problem with my programm. In general: The programm open a page in the browser and show it. If a file on the server exist, the browser will kill by my "taskkiller". After that process, a page on the server will open in a stream and the programm ends. Same procedure if the programm run one Minute (i = 6 with 10 seconds sleep every "i") or the client close the browser.

Now my problem: When the programm ends, should display the screensaver. In my programm work it, but only for few seconds... After few seconds the screensaver is disabled... Why?

-> When I close the browser works it perfectly! But not after one Minute or the file on the server...

This project is very important for me so I hope you can help me!

... and sorry for my bad english.

```
Here is my code:

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;

public class Anzeige {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException, InterruptedException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        if(!exists("url_one")) {

            int i = 0;

            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
                  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                      return new PasswordAuthentication("","".toCharArray());
                  }
              });

              URL test = new URL("url_two");
              BufferedReader open = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test.openStream()));
              open.close();

            String ubergabe = "url_three";

            if(!exists(ubergabe)) {
                try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe \"url_four\"");
                        while(true) {   


                            String line;
                            String pidInfo ="";

                            Process t = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");

                            BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(t.getInputStream()));

                            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                                pidInfo+=line; 
                            }

                            input.close();

                            if(exists(ubergabe) || i >= 6 || !pidInfo.contains("firefox.exe")) { 
                                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe");

                                Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
                                      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                          return new PasswordAuthentication("x","y".toCharArray());
                                      }
                                  });

                                  URL url = new URL("url_five");
                                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                                  br.close();

                                break;
                            } else {
                                i++;
                                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                                Thread.sleep(20);
                                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                                Thread.sleep(9750);
                            }
                        }

                } catch (Exception e) {}        

            }
        }

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\scrnsave.scr /s");
    }


    public static boolean exists(String URLName) {
        try {
          HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
          HttpURLConnection con =
             (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
          con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
          return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return false;
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: The problem must be this snippet:         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe"); - what is false with this snippet?

Comment: The problem was the /F in the taskkiller. When you kill the process "gently" the screensaver doesn't make problems.

Comment: **Never** use the one-String form of exec: [`exec(String command)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) -- **always** use the command-array form instead: [`exec(String[] cmdarray)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])). The _String_ form can easily fail if there are spaces in the command, like `.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox...")` It will think the program to run is `C:\Program` and give it args `1: Files` - `2: (x86)\Mozilla` - `3: Firefox` etc.